# Non-trivial non-symbolic macro definition in CMake

Tags: cmake

I want `__forceinline` to be defined as `__attribute__((always_inline))`, which is obviously possible with compiler flags. Now, how to get the same to work in CMake? The following does horrible things:

```
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    __forceinline=__attribute__((always_inline)))
```

Comment: Have you tried to put `__forceinline=__attribute__((always_inline))` into double quotes? This at least separates this assignment from other arguments for `target_compile_definitions` command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are right, target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "__forceinline=__attribute__((always_inline))") is the solution! Thanks